# What is the difference between Template.created and Template.onCreated in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

`Template.templatename.onCreated` is mentioned in the documentation (along with the `.onRendered` and `.onDestroyed` methods).

But when I call these nothing happens.  If i call `Template.templatename.created` for instance, this works.

Any idea whats going on?  Am I misreading something in the docs?  is this a reference to something else ?

**EDIT : I've just found this in the source :**

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/blaze/template.js#L65

on line 180, these are marked as deprecated in 1.1, but I'm still not getting any love from onCreated....

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Template.channels_admin.onCreated = function () {
    // .... doesn't run
};
```

Comment: those sounds like events.

Comment: They're template callback functions.

Comment: Is your project updated? Run `meteor update` to make sure of it.

Comment: hey,  I get : This project is already at Meteor 1.1.0.2, the latest release.
Your packages are at their latest compatible versions.

Comment: oh wait, code fail. = instead of a callback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to meteor 1.0.4, `created` was a function available to all templates that ran prior to any of the template logic (events, rendering, helpers, etc.). In 1.0.4, it was replaced with [onCreated](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated) which is a function that **registers callbacks** (again each callback runs once before any template logic).

`created` was left in place so as not to break existing code, but is considered deprecated in favor of `onCreated`.

Because `created` was a function on the template, it could be assigned via:

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function() {console.log('here');};
```

`created` should not be called directly.

As you can see from the docs, `onCreated` is called with a function like so:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  console.log('hello');
});
```

The nice thing about `onCreated` is that you can register multiple callbacks for the same template. In practice this may not come up often, however it's nice in cases where you need to attach to a template provided by an external package. This same logic applies to `onRendered` and `onDestroyed`.

Comment: Ding ding ding! thanks david.... I just got my head around that.  after using it so often when I went back to the docs and saw the onCreated I didn't observe its syntax with enough attention.  Cheers.

Comment: are multiple callbacks added like helpers ?  can you demonstrate ?

Comment: They can be. For example: `Template.myTemplate.onCreated(myfunc1); Template.myTemplate.onCreated(myfunc2); `

Comment: fantastic, that makes a lot of sense, and is much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

As of meteor 1.1 the created, rednered and destroyed methods have been deprecated in place of onCreated, onRendered and onDestroyed.

Secondly there is a small change to the syntax previously it was declared like so :

```
Template.channels_admin.created = function () {
    // .... this is deprecated
};
```

But as of 1.1 it should be declared like so :

```
Template.channels_admin.onCreated(function () {
     // .... works like a charm.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`created` is the old `onCreated`.

use it like this `.onCreated(function() {`

this makes it really nice when you write packages.